# Layout issues when working with TabController, NavigationController and NavigationView (SwiftUI) together

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on the iOS legacy codebase with some SwiftUI views built. Everything looks good when app gets launched, but the Tab Bar title will be missing when navigate to another screen (either ViewController or SwiftUI view). It happens when navigate at the first time, the tab bar title will keep missing even though pops back.

[This is how the tab bar looks after launching at the first time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeBFZ.jpg)

[This is how the tab bar looks after navigating the other screens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wGgJ.jpg)

One more issue that I am facing is the navigation bar will be duplicate when navigate to a ViewController from SwiftUI view. The top one will be the nav bar from SwiftUI with a back button, the duplicate one will be from ViewController below the first one without the back button. What I expect is either the one from SwiftUI view with nav bar title, or the one from ViewController with the back button.

[The top one is from SwiftUI view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVrPX.jpg)

Does anyone have some ideas how to fix them? Thank you!